# Change part of a cell to bold

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with cells that cointans only numbers. If the length of the number in the cell is `5`, I want to add `6` in front of the number and `00` at the end of it.
This works so far, but know I also want to make the original number bold but not the `6` and `00`. I tried to turn the whole column bold and then add the `6` and `00`, but that didnt work.

My following code is not working correct with numbers. It only changes the font to bold when I set the Start to `1`, but then it changes the whole cell instead of the `5` numbers. If I replace the numbers with a string it's working fine, so I tried to convert the number to a string, but that didn't work aswell.

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A1:A500").Cells
    If Len(c.Value) = 5 Then
        c.Value = "6" & c.Value & "00"
        c.Value = CStr(c.Value)
        c = CStr(c.Value)
        c.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=5).Font.Bold = True 
    End If
Next
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that `c.Value = CStr(c.Value)` and `c = CStr(c.Value)` does exactly the same because if not specified `c` defaults to `c.Value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting `c` as a text will solve it.

```
c.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Or you can directly format the range before running the code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Excel thinks by default that the numbers should be formatted numerically. And it does not provide the possibility to bold digits of a number. Unless, the number is converted to a text, but then it is a text. By default, numbers are aligned to the right, text is aligned to left:

[image]

There are 2 basic ways to convert a number to text in Excel:

- By explicit conversion - select the number, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, select text. Then record a macro to see the generated code;
- By adding a string to the number - e.g. from `12345` make `a12345` (But this changes the value a bit)

---

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:A5").Cells
        If Len(c.Value) = 5 Then
            c.NumberFormat = "@"
            c.Value = "6" & c.Value & "00"
            c.Characters(Start:=3, Length:=5).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```